# AIR-AS3 4K screen wrong size detected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, desktop

i'm developping a fullscreen app for a multitouch 4K screen

unfornunately the detected screen size is wrong

all these function return 3072x1728 instead of native resolution 3840x2160

```
trace("screenres : " + Capabilities.screenResolutionX + "x" + Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
trace("mainbounds : " + Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width + "x" + Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height);
trace("mainvisible : " + Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds.width + "x" + Screen.mainScreen.visibleBounds.height);
trace("stagesize : " + _stage.stageWidth + "x" + _stage.stageHeight);
trace("windowsize : " + _stage.nativeWindow.width + "x" + _stage.nativeWindow.height);
trace("fullsize : " + _stage.fullScreenWidth + "x" + _stage.fullScreenHeight);
```

i searched for an hour on google, adobe forums and more but can't find any clue why it does this.

does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest AIR sdk or latest flash player? 
If so, add a bug in the adobe bugbase. Capabilities.screenres should definitely return the correct value

What device are you testing on?

There are ANEs for AIR mobile you can use for now to pull the correct resolution information

Comment: i'm using latest AIR SDK 23 running on Windows 10 Pro with GTX 1080 and a 4K multitouch screen from mmt.io, the windows native resolution is correct.

Comment: Yeah i would log a bug in the bugbase. I dont think air devs are seeing many other 4k screens yet but im sure its coming. Capabilities.screenres definitely needs to be correct.

Comment: I would add the exact model of screen to your bug report. Also check out this newly reported bug it sounds similar to yours. They state the windows font size is affecting Capabilities.screenresolution. https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4196015

Comment: you're right this was the problem, so not really a bug but this should be fixed because setting the size to 100% on MS Surface makes everything unclickable / readable.